Why does nobody in Tolkien's stories ever attempt to question or reason with Melkor?
I've read The Hobbit, LotR, The Silmarillion and am now well into the second "Lost tales" book.
That poor father that Melkor put in a prison on a high hill to force him to sit there and remotely watch through a disturbing "reality TV show" the misfortunes of his Melkor-hexed son, is eventually let go by Melkor. He stands with him and talks in a physical and direct manner -- not letting some servants deal with his prisoner as is sometimes the case -- and gives him every opportunity to... talk to the Dark Lord. Not to mention he probably visited him many times during the many years he was a prisoner, if only to taunt him.
Yet not a single word of questioning/reasoning with him. Not the slightest hint of an attempt or even will to do so, or even thinking about how it would go.
This annoyed me about the Ainur/Valar as well. None of them ever bring up any sort of questioning of Melkor's motivations or end goals. It seems as if every single entity in Tolkien's universe, be they wise and ancient gods or lowly mortal humans, assumes that Melkor per definition is purely evil and cannot possibly be convinced to stop or at least be a little less evil. As if it would be an utter waste of time or dangerous to even try.
Naturally, I don't mean that they should go like: "Yo, Melkor! Cut out all this evil stuff, will ya? It's not nice!" They would obviously wrap it deeply in flattering words as to just mildly question whether all of his actions really are for the best, as to not make him too defensive or needlessly anger him.
It may very well be that he is helplessly evil, but why do we never get one single piece of dialogue (unless this indeed happens in one of the stories that I have left) in which some life-form for once asks Melkor or even any of his servants why he wants things to be miserable and dark and dissonant and against Illuvatar's wishes? Basically: "What is the basic disagreement? And if you will not change your mind, is there something that we can do to make you not hate us?"
Even if his responses are almost certainly going to be sly lies, many of the things that Melkor or his creatures express seem to suggest that they are not merely blinded by raw, pure hate, but creatures capable of complex and sophisticated thoughts. Even if the response ultimately is that he's "just a sick sadist", it would be very interesting to hear how this would be described by himself or his allies.
From memory, his minions tend to refer to him in an extremely generic manner such as "Morgoth The Great", etc., but never explaining why what he does would be so great in the eyes of his followers. It's never explained by his allies and these are also never questioned about it by "the good guys", which is even odder. Things are just assumed to be this way and apparently this fundamental conflict is somehow not worthy of a word of explanation or elaboration in any of the stories.
This feels like the case of a troubled boy in a school class where neither the other kids nor the grown-ups ever say a word to this bully but merely assume that nothing could ever make him less of a bully so it's meaningless to even try to be friendly to him.

Does anyone in the Bible try to talk to any devils/demons and persuade them to not be evil? Melkor's character and motivations are established at the start, and once he's locked in his "Dark Lord" form we are told there is no going back. The other characters don't need to ask him about it, because that's not how epic mythology works.

@OrangeDog yes they try. It even has a donkey trying to reason with Balaam for, ah, Xssake.

(Comment because I don't have sources available to quote directly) They did try to reason with Melkor back during his trial, and he convinced them to forgive him, and that he would rejoin them. This of course ended with him betraying them all. I suspect that after this basically everyone decided that talking to him would just end with you being cursed and deceived. Aside from that, the Silmarillion is also written more like a history book, and thus tends to skip over conversations or just note the outcome, especially when they weren't actually important.

This really isn't true.  Melkor at one point is believed to be reformed and is paroled from the Halls of Mandos.  This surely did not happen without some conversation, even if we don't get to hear it all.

Melkor is one of the most abused beings in all of Middle-earth history. Many people are saying Melkor is the greatest leader Middle-earth could possibly have. Lock up the corrupt Ainur now and stop this mad witch-hunt!

@PaulD.Waite I hear he's selling his own version of The Silmarillion for a very reasonable price.

There was this guy named Mairon who tried it. "Hey man, what you're doing is messy and that makes me uncomfortable. "

@Spencer that relationship really turned sour on reflection.

@PaulD.Waite I suspect it might be worth examining who wrote the history books. It wouldn't have been, you know, the victors...? Brings to mind The Last Ringbearer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Last_Ringbearer

Neville Chamberlain had a chat with that German Chancellor, and came away thinking he wanted peace. Morgoth was a nihilist who wanted to destroy what he couldn't have, and he wanted everything.

@DanielHatton Here's one take: https://saurons.home.blog/2019/12/30/3-melkor-seems-like-a-really-cool-guy/
